# Thread pool threads don't accept new AsyncTasks

Tags: android, android-asynctask, threadpoolexecutor

I have several AsyncTasks being executed by `AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR`.
Once five threads have been created (which is the default core pool size), the new tasks are queued instead of being executed on the threads in the pool which should be idle and awaiting new tasks at that point, since the previous tasks run on them have finished (that is their status, and also .cancel(true) has been called). The queued tasks never get executed. the situation remains as such until the app is shut down completely (settings>force stop) and restarted.

What could be the reason the threads in the pool do not accept new tasks?

The execution call is as follows:

`new TestTask().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);`

The queueing is being handled by the executor and not by me directly.

Comment: Can you post the code where you queue and execute the threads, otherwise it's guessing. A sample of one of the tasks would be good too in case it's tied up due to a leak